# Where is the source of H+ in the matrix that will be pumped during the electron transfer system?　Where does the OH generated at that time go?

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, cellular-respiration, energy-metabolism

In the electron transfer system, it has been mentioned in prior questions that complexes I, III, and IV are proton pumps and that these pumps pump protons from the matrix into the intermembrane space.

- [Does the formation of water inside the mitochondrial matrix help contribute to the proton gradient during the electron transport chain?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/47981/does-the-formation-of-water-inside-the-mitochondrial-matrix-help-contribute-to-t)
- [Electron Transport Chain Proton Pumping into the Intermembrane Space](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/81668/electron-transport-chain-proton-pumping-into-the-intermembrane-space)
- [How many protons are pumped out per pair of electrons from NADH in oxidative phosphorylation?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/42560/how-many-protons-are-pumped-out-per-pair-of-electrons-from-nadh-in-oxidative-pho?rq=1)

> My question.
>
> - However, where are the protons in the matrix supplied from?
> - In other words, where does the OH- generated when the protons are generated in the matrix disappear?
> - Why is it not biased to the alkaline side to the extreme even though the number of proton is decreasing rapidly due to being pumped out or used to dispose of surplus electrons?

In particular, it seems that the **Protons** in the matrix are used to dispose of surplus electrons in the electron transfer system by combining with externally introduced O2 to produce H2O, but this seems to result in too much OH-. I would like to know the fate of the excess alkali.

See also,
https://bio.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_California_Davis/BIS_105%3A__Biomolecules_and_Metabolism_%28Murphy%29/Electron_Transport_System

Comment: What "H2" are you referring to? Are you familiar with [pH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PH) and dissociation of water into OH- and H+ (or H3O+)?

Comment: That typ. You're right, it's a proton.

Comment: I know that there exists a chemical equilibrium in which the ionization product is constant. Both H+ and OH- should be produced in the process. And if the H+ produced is pumped out, the OH will be left behind.
The protons may be used to dispose of the excess electrons, but in that case they will combine with externally introduced O2 instead of OH-. So there is even more OH- left over.

In the process, it is likely that there will be more and more OH- only.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear which part it is you're exactly trying to understand...is it that you're wondering where the "H+" comes from that combines with O2 to make H2O? Or are you wondering about the H+ pumped through the membrane?

Comment: Fate? Nothing. There is nothing in chemistry, thermodynamics or  Nature that says a cellular compartment cannot have a particular non-neutral pH. It remains alkaline until the pH gradient is used to make ATP.